# Android restlet slow speed

Tags: android, performance, wcf, odata, restlet

I am using [Restlet framework](http://restlet.com/downloads/current/#release=stable&edition=android&distribution=zip) to communicate with WCF Odata services from [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet) article.
Everything is fine, but it takes too much time to get entity from service(about 10 sec.).
Can anybody explain me, how to configure restlet for android to speedup requests?
Hete is some code from my app:

```
DataService service=new DataService();
service.setCredentials(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,login,password));
Query<Employee> employees=service.createEmployeesQuery("/Employees").filter("EmpIsDeleted eq false");
for(Employee employee:employees){
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, 10s for a call is a lot of time! Did you try to call the service from a browser (`http://.../Employees?$filter=EmpIsDeleted eq false`)? Do you try to execute your Restlet code within a standalone Java application? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tried it from browser. It took about 1 second to load 200 entities. Any ideas? To run this code from separate java application I should use other restlet framework. Recently I detected that method createEmployeesQuery takes the most. But in fact entities are loaded after call execute() in class Query.

Comment: I tried to test it on [Northwind odata service](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/) and I still have very slow speed.

Comment: Great if you have made tests on an OData v3 that can also reach ;-) For your information, three calls are actually made: one on the service (`xx.svc`), one for metadata (`xx.svc/$metadata`) and one for the specified query. I'll make some tests with several tools (from browser, Restlet and Olingo) and will write a detailled answer...

Comment: ideally .svc / $metadata are cached and re-used, so that only the first call will be slow compared to subsequent calls.